# How to add external JavaScript and CSS into backend module in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid

I am working with TYPO3 CMS. I would like to add external JavaScript and CSS into a backend module, but I am actually not sure how to add these. Could you guide me how to implement that?

Answer (score 7):

Via FLUID template fx: Layout/Default.html

```
<f:be.container
  includeCssFiles="{0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'Css/Styles.css\')}'}"
  includeJsFiles="{0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'JavaScript/Library1.js\')}', 1: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'JavaScript/Library2.js\')}'}">
your module content
</f:be.container>
```

Comment: The `f:be.container` view-helper also adds additional boilerplate markup that is used for backend modules (header,footer, ...). It's possible to use `f:be.pageRenderer` as an alternative which just concerns the resource loading aspects of stylesheet and JavaScript files.

Comment: Ya, `f:be.container` is deprecated since TYPO3v11 and removed in TYPO3v12. Use `f:be.pageRenderer` as mentioned by Oliver Hader. But works only, if your Controller renders via ModuleTemplate. See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.3/Deprecation-94225-FbecontainerViewHelper.html